# Probability Theorems

Tags: probability

There are six blue balls and five red balls in a box. Two balls are randomly taken one by one with replacement. 
i) what is the probability of choosing one blue ball and one red ball?
my answer for this is 30/55
ii) what is the probability of choosing at least one red ball?
my answer for this is 85/121

Comment: People will be more willing to help you if you explain your thinking and process rather than writing answers.

Comment: my answer for  i) n(e) 6C1*5C1= 30 n(s) 11C1= 11!/2! = 55. thus, 30/55 but the answer given was 60/121. i don't know how to get them.

Comment: i) The idea is "with replacement", this means that each time a ball is taken, the ball is put back in the box. Also choosing one blue and one red can be two things: 1. first choosing blue and second choosing red or 2. first choosing red and second choosing blue

Answer (score 2):

So we have two trials, and each trial has $P(b) = \frac{6}{11}$ and $P(r) = \frac{5}{11}$.
This is just a binomial distribution.

So $P(\text{1 blue in two trials}) = \binom{2}{1}P(b)^1(1-P(b))^1 = 2\frac{5}{11}\frac{6}{11} = \frac{60}{121}$

And $P(\text{at least 1 red in two trials}) = 1-P(\text{2 blue in 2 trials}) = 1- \binom{2}{2}P(b)^2(1-P(b))^0 = 1 - (\frac{6}{11})^2 = \frac{121-36}{121} = \frac{85}{121}$

Comment: There are 6 blue balls, so 2 blue in 2 trials should be $\frac{36}{121}$

Comment: @ClarkMakmur thx for spotting that, so edited.

Comment: i still don't get it. did you get 6/11^2?

Comment: @cheezybang 1 minus the square of 6 over 11, yes

Answer (score 0):

Note that it states "with replacement", which implies: you pick one ball, check its color, put it back in the box, then pick again. So, for a):
$$P(B_1\cap R_2)+P(R_1\cap B_2)=\frac6{11}\cdot \frac5{11}+\frac5{11}\cdot \frac6{11}=\frac{60}{121}.$$
And you calculated for "without replacement", which implies: you pick one ball, check its color, put it outside of the box, then pick again. So:
$$P(B_1\cap R_2)+P(R_1\cap B_2)=\frac6{11}\cdot \frac5{10}+\frac5{11}\cdot \frac6{10}=\frac{60}{110}=\frac{30}{55}.$$
Can you handle b)?

Answer (score -1):

Probability choosing first blue and second red
$$\frac{6}{11}*\frac{5}{11}=\frac{30}{121}$$
Probability choosing first red and second blue
$$\frac{5}{11}*\frac{6}{11}=\frac{30}{121}$$
Probability choosing one blue and one red
$$\frac{30}{121}+\frac{30}{121}=\frac{60}{121}$$

Comment: oh okay. now i got it. thank you!

Comment: so for the second question is

Comment: find the probability of two reds, and add with the result in (i)